# Agora io - Edit remote video frames

Tags: android, android-studio, agora.io

I am looking to create a video streaming Android app which edits the remote video frames. Is it possible to do so in Agora?

I found ways to edit the frames in video source (push method and MediaIO) but could not find anything that allows editing the remote video frames. I want to be able to edit the received video frames differently depending upon the user information so cannot modify in the source.

Comment: Hey Dines. Can you share a bit more about your use case? How exactly do you want to edit the video frames?

Comment: Hi Samyak. Thank you for the response. I would like to do some image manipulations - something like applying filter to the image or adding an object in the image. Basically, what I want to achieve is - read a frame from the player, modify the frame image (using opencv or other library), display the modified frame image.

Comment: You cannot make changes to the video frames on the server side. You will need to change the video frames at the source. Let's take a use case of A and B on a 1-1 video call, if you want to modify A's remote, you will need to work on changing B's local video. This solution would also scale better.

Comment: Let's say there are three users, A, B & C. C is streaming while A and B are viewing. Is it possible to modify C's video on A and B's device? I want this because I would like to modify C's video differently for A and B and not the same modifications. If I modify C's video on C's device, I cannot customize it differently for A and B.

Comment: Yes. You can use the Raw Video Data on C. On C's device, you can process A and B's video different based on their UID and display it to C how you want it to. You can read our guide here about it: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/raw_data_video_android?platform=Android. You can look at using the following callback: onRenderVideoFrame

Comment: Thanks @Samyak, I wanted exactly this. However, when I try to implement this as shown in documentation and the API Example, I cannot seem to get anything in the callbacks onRenderVideoFrame and onCaptureVideoFrame. Could you know what could be the reason? I've also posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457878/cannot-get-raw-video-frame-in-agora