# Cannot get raw video frame in Agora

Tags: java, android, android-studio, agora.io

I am trying to create a video calling Android application using Agora SDK but I'm running into a problem. I want to capture the video frames and process it before displaying it.

I am using the `lib-raw-data` from API Examples to capture the raw video frame. I have followed the steps from the documentation https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/raw_data_video_android?platform=Android and checked the examples as well. However, I cannot seem to capture the frame in methods `onRenderVideoFrame` and `onCaptureVideoFrame`.

The video calling works perfectly but the callback function does not seem to work. I don't get anything in onRenderVideoFrame or onCaptureVideoFrame.

Below is the code for the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaDataVideoObserver,
        MediaDataAudioObserver {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 22;

    private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    private RtcEngine mRtcEngine;
    private boolean mCallEnd;
    private boolean mMuted;

    private FrameLayout mLocalContainer;
    private RelativeLayout mRemoteContainer;
    private VideoCanvas mLocalVideo;
    private VideoCanvas mRemoteVideo;

    private ImageView mCallBtn;
    private ImageView mMuteBtn;
    private ImageView mSwitchCameraBtn;
    private MediaDataObserverPlugin mediaDataObserverPlugin;

    private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
            super.onJoinChannelSuccess(channel, uid, elapsed);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("Agora", "Join channel success, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFirstRemoteVideoFrame(int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) {
            super.onFirstRemoteVideoFrame(uid, width, height, elapsed);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("Agora", "First remote video decoded, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                    setupRemoteVideo(uid);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserOffline(int uid, int reason) {
            super.onUserOffline(uid, reason);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
                        mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeDecodeBuffer(uid);
                    }
                    Log.i("Agora", "User offline, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                    onRemoteUserLeft(uid);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed) {
            super.onUserJoined(uid, elapsed);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("agora", "Remote user joined, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                    setupRemoteVideo(uid);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private void onRemoteUserLeft(int uid) {
        if (mRemoteVideo != null && mRemoteVideo.uid == uid) {
            removeFromParent(mRemoteVideo);
            // Destroys remote view
            mRemoteVideo = null;
        }
    }

    private ViewGroup removeFromParent(VideoCanvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            ViewParent parent = canvas.view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) parent;
                group.removeView(canvas.view);
                return group;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void showButtons(boolean show) {
        int visibility = show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        mMuteBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
        mSwitchCameraBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUI();

        Log.e(TAG, "Media Data Observer registered");
        // Ask for permissions at runtime.
        if (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
                checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
                checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[2], PERMISSION_REQ_ID)) {
            initEngineAndJoinChannel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
            mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeVideoObserver(this);
            mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAllBuffer();
        }
    }

    private void initUI() {
        mLocalContainer = findViewById(R.id.local_video_view_container);
        mRemoteContainer = findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);

        mCallBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        mMuteBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_mute);
        mSwitchCameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_switch_camera);

    }

    private boolean checkSelfPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, requestCode);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void initEngineAndJoinChannel() {

        initializeEngine();
        setupVideoConfig();
        setupLocalVideo();
        joinChannel();
    }

    private void joinChannel() {
        String token = "<access token>";
        mediaDataObserverPlugin = MediaDataObserverPlugin.the();
        MediaPreProcessing.setCallback(mediaDataObserverPlugin);
        MediaPreProcessing.setVideoCaptureByteBuffer(mediaDataObserverPlugin.byteBufferCapture);
        mediaDataObserverPlugin.addVideoObserver(this);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
            token = null;
        }

        mRtcEngine.setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION);

        mRtcEngine.joinChannel(token, "channel1", "", 0);

    }

    private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
        ViewGroup parent = mRemoteContainer;
        if (mLocalVideo != null && parent.indexOfChild(mLocalVideo.view) > -1) {
            parent = mLocalContainer;
        }

        if (mRemoteVideo != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
            mediaDataObserverPlugin.addDecodeBuffer(uid);
        }
        SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
        view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(parent == mLocalContainer);
        parent.addView(view);
        mRemoteVideo = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, uid);
        // Initializes the video view of a remote user.
        mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(mRemoteVideo);
    }


    private void setupLocalVideo() {
        SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
        view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        mLocalContainer.addView(view);
        // Initializes the local video view.
        // RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN: Uniformly scale the video until it fills the visible boundaries. One dimension of the video may have clipped contents.
        VideoCanvas localVideoCanvas = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, 0);
        mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(localVideoCanvas);
        //mRtcEngine.setVideoSource(new CustomVideoSource());

    }

    private void setupVideoConfig() {
        // In simple use cases, we only need to enable video capturing
        // and rendering once at the initialization step.
        // Note: audio recording and playing is enabled by default.
        mRtcEngine.enableVideo();

        mRtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration(
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.VD_640x360,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_15,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.STANDARD_BITRATE,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT));
    }

    private void initializeEngine() {
        try {
            mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcHandler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Agora", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            throw new RuntimeException("Check rtc sdk init fatal error - " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }

    private void startCall() {
        setupLocalVideo();
        joinChannel();
    }

    private void endCall() {
        removeFromParent(mLocalVideo);
        mLocalVideo = null;
        removeFromParent(mRemoteVideo);
        mRemoteVideo = null;
        leaveChannel();
    }

    private void leaveChannel() {
        if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
            mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeVideoObserver(this);
            mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAllBuffer();
        }
        mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();
    }

    public void onLocalAudioMuteClicked(View view) {
        mMuted = !mMuted;
        // Stops/Resumes sending the local audio stream.
        mRtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(mMuted);
        int res = mMuted ? R.drawable.btn_mute : R.drawable.btn_unmute;
        mMuteBtn.setImageResource(res);
    }

    public void onSwitchCameraClicked(View view) {
        // Switches between front and rear cameras.
        mRtcEngine.switchCamera();
    }

    public void onCallClicked(View view) {
        if (mCallEnd) {
            startCall();
            mCallEnd = false;
            mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_endcall);
        } else {
            endCall();
            mCallEnd = true;
            mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_startcall);
        }

        showButtons(!mCallEnd);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!mCallEnd) {
            leaveChannel();
        }
        /*
          Destroys the RtcEngine instance and releases all resources used by the Agora SDK.
          This method is useful for apps that occasionally make voice or video calls,
          to free up resources for other operations when not making calls.
         */
        RtcEngine.destroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRecordAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing(int uid, byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMixedAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureVideoFrame(byte[] data, int frameType, int width, int height, int bufferLength, int yStride, int uStride, int vStride, int rotation, long renderTimeMs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureVideoFrame called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderVideoFrame(int uid, byte[] data, int frameType, int width, int height, int bufferLength, int yStride, int uStride, int vStride, int rotation, long renderTimeMs) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onRenderVideoFrame called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreEncodeVideoFrame(byte[] data, int frameType, int width, int height, int bufferLength, int yStride, int uStride, int vStride, int rotation, long renderTimeMs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreEncodeVideoFrame0");
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.agoratest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:3.3.1'

    implementation project(path: ':lib-raw-data')
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for being late on this. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi! I haven't been able to solve this. I have followed the documentation, but can't seem to get it work? The callbacks (onRenderVideoFrame, onCaptureVideoFrame) are never reached. Is there an obvious issue that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. Have you filed a support ticket at https://agora-ticket.agora.io/?